# Why can't I access IIS Manager on my server with Reporting Services installed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs

I have a Windows Server 2008 Server running SQL Server 2012 (including SSRS). I've noticed that the site is intermittently slow on first run, and found [this blog post](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2197/how-to-speed-up-ms-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-on-first-run/) about the cause and how to fix it.

However, when I open the server manager for either of my servers (dev and production) they don't seem to have IIS installed.

Production:

[image]

On my dev server, I installed the IIS role, but I can't see anything to do with Reporting Services there:

[image]

Why can't I see anything to do with SSRS here? The web sites for both servers work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of SQL Server 2008, IIS is no longer used by SQL Server Reporting Services. It utilizes the HTTP.sys API now. So you will not see SSRS show up as a site or application pool.

The tip you linked to deals with SQL Server 2005, which required IIS in order to use SSRS. [This tip](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2735/prevent-sql-server-reporting-services-slow-startup/) speaks of the slowness you might be seeing and how to address it in SQL Server 2008/2008 R2. I would test to see if the same results are seen in 2012 version.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Do you have an official source explaining this change by any chance?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143380(v=sql.100).aspx